# How to implement new pooling technique in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I thought of implementing a new pooling layer, how can I add it to tensorflow as a new layer.
Couldn't understand the Tensorflow codebase.
Any leads on how to begin shall be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a new tensorflow operation for pooling you can take a look at: https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op.

You might also want to look at their github and add a pull request if multiple people could use this: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow.